# smartctl not performing test on hard disk

Tags: smart

I have a SATA hard drive connected to a SAS card through a backplane in an Intel server.   The drive appears quite accessible in Linux, however I notice some strange errors in the logs.   I want to see if these are to do with spin up/initialization issues or something else, so I wanted to do a S.M.A.R.T test.

The device reports "overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED" but I wanted to run some S.M.A.R.T tests myself.  I am unsure why this is failing and my Google-foo is letting me down.

Can anyone explain what the following means and if I can work around this - preferably without taking the drive offline:

```
=== START OF OFFLINE IMMEDIATE AND SELF-TEST SECTION ===
Sending command: "Execute SMART Short self-test routine immediately in captive mode".
Command "Execute SMART Short self-test routine immediately in captive mode" failed: Connection timed out
```

(This is in response to the command "smartctl -t short -C /dev/sdd")

Comment: Did you read the **man** page?  Why are you using the `-C` option (i.e. that seems contradictory to your stated goal of not *"taking the drive offline"*, and the root cause of your problem)?

Comment: @sawdust thank you for this.  I had read a (wrong I guess) doc that says it just does not background the test, ie waits for it to complete.

Answer (score 1):

The "captive" mode seems unsupported (at least on Linux?), which is sadly not stated anywhere I looked.

So I've run into this same issue, thinking "captive" foreground tests would have full priority and available bandwidth and thus finish faster. But that seems not to be the case. So the `smartctl` manpage is misleading.

As part of a captive self-test, the smartctl process keeps waiting for the drive to finish and return. However, the SATA subsystem detects this outstanding command as a hang of the drive, and aborts after `/sys/block/<blockdev>/device/timeout` seconds have passed.

`dmesg` will log the drive reset (in my instance hanging off of an Adaptec controller),

[image: dmesg error log]

```
[May 7 17:28] aacraid: Host adapter abort request.
              aacraid: Outstanding commands on (0,1,3,0):
[ +28.668009] aacraid: Host adapter abort request.
              aacraid: Outstanding commands on (0,1,3,0):
[  +0.024081] aacraid: Host bus reset request. SCSI hang ?
[  +0.000006] aacraid 0000:06:00.0: outstanding cmd: midlevel-0
[  +0.000002] aacraid 0000:06:00.0: outstanding cmd: lowlevel-0
[  +0.000001] aacraid 0000:06:00.0: outstanding cmd: error handler-1
[  +0.000001] aacraid 0000:06:00.0: outstanding cmd: firmware-0
[  +0.000001] aacraid 0000:06:00.0: outstanding cmd: kernel-0
[  +0.019997] aacraid 0000:06:00.0: Controller reset type is 3
[  +0.000004] aacraid 0000:06:00.0: Issuing IOP reset
[May 7 17:29] aacraid 0000:06:00.0: IOP reset succeeded
[  +0.033805] aacraid: Comm Interface type2 enabled
[  +2.217498] udevd[558]: worker [9103] /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0c.0/0000:06:00.0/host0/target0:1:3/0:1:3:0/block/sdd is taking a long time
[  +6.814903] aacraid 0000:06:00.0: Scheduling bus rescan
[ +10.192816] sd 0:1:3:0: [sdd] tag#543 timing out command, waited 60s
[  +0.000007] sd 0:1:3:0: [sdd] tag#543 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_RESET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=109s
[  +0.000003] sd 0:1:3:0: [sdd] tag#543 CDB: ATA command pass through(16) 85 06 0c 00 d4 00 00 00 81 00 4f 00 c2 00 b0 00
[  +0.001052] sd 0:1:3:0: [sdd] 11721045168 512-byte logical blocks: (6.00 TB/5.46 TiB)
[  +0.000005] sd 0:1:3:0: [sdd] 4096-byte physical blocks
[  +0.003122]  sdd: sdd1 sdd2
```

and the drive then logs a failed selftest:

```
SMART Extended Self-test Log Version: 1 (1 sectors)
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short captive       Interrupted (host reset)      50%       196         -
```

The ticket describing this issue with `smartmontools` has been marked as "wontfix": https://www.smartmontools.org/ticket/1153

I don't think increasing the block device timeout is a solution for an extended selftest.
So we can't run captive tests, I guess. (Perhaps it's different for native SCSI drives?)